# put ranges to a variable when defining a function

Tags: r, function, range

Hi i want to have this:

```
fun <- function(t) { sin(2*pi*t) - 0.5*cos(2*pi*t)}
```

but taking on account

```
a 0 < t < 10
```

How can I plot the function with the t restriction?

My code is

```
  fun <- function(t) { sin(2*pi*t) - 0.5*cos(2*pi*t)} 

  plot(fun, xlim = c(0,10))
```

How can I do it without xlim?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `from` and `to`:

```
plot(fun,from=0,to=10,xlim=c(-10,20))
```

[image: from-and-to]

Or alternatively in `ggplot2`, first set up dummy plot window, then use `stat_function` with both `xlim` and `scale_x_continuous`. Notice how `xlim` works much differently here than in base R.

```
fun <- function(t) { sin(2*pi*t) - 0.5*cos(2*pi*t)} 
p <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0), mapping=aes(x=x))
p + stat_function(fun=fun, xlim=c(0,10)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-10,20))
```

[image]